# AMPScript to replace first two digits in a phone number

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Due to a phone validation requirement and our storage of phone numbers in marketing cloud, I need an AMP script to replace the 61 at the start of a mobile number with 0.

Anyone experienced this before or know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need, is Regular Expressions.
Adam Spriggs has a [neat guide on this](https://sprignaturemoves.com/regex-in-ampscript/), which you can use for reference

```
var @s, @o, @p, @m

output(concat("<br>Replace leading 61 in a string"))
set @s = "6122334455"
set @p = "^(61{1})(\d+)$"
set @m = RegExMatch(@s, @p, 1)
set @o = replace(@s, "61", "0")
output(concat("<br>input:  ", @s))
output(concat('<br>pattern: "', @p, '"'))
output(concat("<br>output: 0", @o,RegExMatch(@s, @p, 2)))
```

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear with my question! I'm still relatively new to SF esp ampscript. The link i have to insert the number into is www.url.com/mobile=%%PersonMobilePhone%%. The field PersonMobilePhone starts with 61, which needs to be replaced with a 0. How would you RE work with these requirements? I've tried a couple of interpretations with no luck!

Comment: Hi Matthew. You want to use the final output string (regardless if you use my or the approach of Gortonington), and concat it with the rest of URL, i.e. @finalurl=Concat("www.url.com/mobile=",@fixedmobile). You then should use RedirectTo function, taking @finalurl as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

RegEx is a great solution, but sometimes it can be similar to using a sawzall to cut a piece of paper - which can cause the effort to outweigh the benefit.

My solution for simple replacements is to do an Indexof(), Substring() and Concat() to handle this. It is much more intuitive to understand and can be easily updated as needed. The catch is that it can become cumbersome as the complexity increases as it will grow verbose very quickly - Which is where RegEx comes in.

```
%%[

SET @phone = "612345678890"
SET @indexPhone = IndexOf(@phone, "61")

IF @indexPhone > 0 OR NOT EMPTY(@indexPhone) THEN

  SET @length = Length(@phone)
  SET @subPhone = Substring(@phone, 3, @length)
  SET @phoneFinal = CONCAT("0", @subPhone)

ELSE

  SET @phoneFinal = @phone

ENDIF

SET @mobileURL = CONCAT("http://www.url.com/mobile=", @phoneFinal)

]%%

<a href="%%=v(@mobileURL)=%%">your Link</a>
```

This will output `@mobileURL` as http://www.url.com/mobile=02345678890.

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear with my question! I'm still relatively new to SF esp ampscript. The link i have to insert the number into is www.url.com/mobile=%%PersonMobilePhone%%. The field PersonMobilePhone starts with 61, which needs to be replaced with a 0. How would you RE work with these requirements? I've tried a couple of interpretations with no luck!

Comment: adjusted my answer to fit in your need.